# What is the JSLint approved way to convert a number to a string?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've always converted numbers to strings by adding an empty string to them:

`var string = 1 + '';`

However, JSLint complains of this method with `Expected 'String' and instead saw ''''.`, and it does look a little ugly.

Is there a better way?

Comment: i checked and it said its valid

Comment: Try it on jslint.com, it fails there. I'm using JSLint edge.

Comment: Fails on jslint.com up front as well. Is this a jslint edge bug?

Comment: @Samuel Cole Then report a bug. I don't use jslint as I strongly disagree with it. It (that which is posted in the question) is entirely valid Javascript. Don't be tied back by someone eleses whims.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the validation @pst. I was just wondering if there was a rational explanation for it before I started filing bugs.

Comment: I always use `''+n` too. Screw JSLint. Works all the time. Validators... pff

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that the JSLint approved way is to call `.toString()` on the number:

```
var stringified = 1..toString();
// Note the use of the double .. to ensure the the interpreter knows 
// that we are calling the toString method on a number -- 
// not courting a syntax error.
// You could also theoretically call 1["toString"];
```

Comment: That's the ticket. 1.toString() was failing in the console for that reason.

Comment: `(1).toString()` would do, `String(1)` also, and furthermore the conversion is implicitly done on for example 'duck'+1 (JsLint approved). JsLint only disagrees with addition of an empty string, which somehow makes sense: why would anyone do `var ducked = 'duck'+''`?

Answer (score 8):

(Sorry, it possibly would've been better to say this as a comment above but I haven't yet earned the right to post comments, so...)

Remember that jslint is not just validating whether your JavaScript will actually run, it is trying to enforce coding style with the aim of helping you produce more readable and maintainable code.

So `1 + ''` *works*, but isn't necessarily the most readable option for everybody while explicit casting options (see the other answers) should be readable for everybody. Of course if nobody else will ever see your code you need only worry about whether you will be able to understand it if you come back to it next month, or next year...

Don't forget that the following two statements don't produce the same result:

```
var s1 = 1 + 3 + ''; // gives '4'
var s2 = '' + 1 + 3; // gives '13'
```

I assume `1 + ''` is just a simplification for discussion though, or why not just use `'1'` in the first place?

Comment: I actually have 3 integers that I want to combine to a string (like in s2) - what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: @DanielG. `result = '' + 1 + 2 + 3;` will result in the string `'123'`. You can concatenate variables the same way.

Comment: Sure, that's what I'm doing at the moment - but this is not "Lint-Valid". :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.toString()` method like so:

```
var num = 1;
var str = num.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also (at least in Chrome): `String(1)` without `new`.

```
var n = 1, s = String(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to say "bug" or "mis-feature"

Cole Consider that

```
var x = "foobar" + 1;
```

is "approved" jslint. In any case, it is 100% valid Javascript.

Happy coding.

---

For comment:

This is why I prefer to *use the string literal as the first operand* as this shows intent -- knowing a language is fundamental to using a language.

The only place the duck-typing is an issues (in this case) is with an expression of the form `a + b`, where neither is a string literal. In this case `a` (or `b`) may evaluate to a string where it was expected to evaluate to a number (this would trigger the string concatenation vs. the expected numeric addition). If any of the operands are a string literal the intent is well-defined/described.

This particular "issue", however, is not present in the posted code; nor would it be eliminated with the use of `toString` over a string literal.

Comment: Yeah, but 1 + '' is ugly. It doesn't actually describe what we want, it just works as a coincidence of duck-typing

Comment: Sure but as mentioned in another answer, doesn't 1..toString() make it even more clear?

Comment: @Samuel Cole Not to me. Why would it? I also like/utilized the fact that I can do `"" + x` and not explode when x is null or undefined. (This isn't always desired, but knowing the rules allows one to make an appropriate decision as far as what construct is acceptable.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm absolutely not arguing against the case where you want to build a string including a number: `console.log('I have ' + number_of_ducks + ' ducks!');` I'm arguing against using concatenation simply for casting. Not having an exception thrown is valuable, but I think a try..catch might be in order in that case.

Comment: @Samuel Cole I don't consider the operations to be different. The end result is a string representation of the number following a particular rule. In any case, I prefer to write code that is "idempotent" to structural changes and selectively using `toString` does not further this cause.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, we should use `String(number)` instead of `number + ''` or `number.toString()`, because

- `number + ''` will trigger the JSLint error
- `number.toString()` will fail in case `number` is `null` or `undefined`, and you will have *TypeError: number is undefined / null*

Answer (score 0):

Recently, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) was in beta. The new version no longer complains about this code:

```
function convert(x) {
    'use strict';
    // alert(typeof x);
    x = x + "";
    // alert(typeof x);
    return x;
}


convert(3);
```