# How can I rectify " Expected String instead saw "" " using jslint?

Tags: jslint

I've got a regular expression:

```
return (str+'').replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function ( $1 ) { return $1.toUpperCase ( ); } );
```

I get following jslint error:

```
Expected String instead saw ""
```

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the JSLint approved way to convert a number to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821950/what-is-the-jslint-approved-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string)

Comment: What should I do in this case? <return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;> I have the same warning.

Answer (score 10):

It wants you to use

```
String(str)
```

isntead of

```
(str+'')
```

Invoking the String function as a "cast" is a slightly cleaner way to convert something to a string from some other type.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use toString();
(new Date()).getTime()+""; instead (new Date()).getTime().toString();
```