# Converting Google Maps styles array to Google Static Maps styles string

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I've built a tool that allows folks to apply a JSON map style to a Google Map, and am now wanting to add support for the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Using the following styles array:

`"[{"stylers":[]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"color":"#d2dce6"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":1},{"color":"#d5858f"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#555555"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFFFFF"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":60}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFFFFF"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"off"}]}]"`

[(More documentation on format)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

I need to ultimately convert this into a URLescaped string, in the format: `style=feature:featureArgument|element:elementArgument|rule1:rule1Argument|rule2:rule2Argument` [(More documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps)

So far, I've written this JavaScript to try and convert things, but it isn't working properly:

```
  function get_static_style(styles) {
    var result = '';
    styles.forEach(function(v, i, a){
      if (v.stylers.length > 0) { // Needs to have a style rule to be valid.
        result += (v.hasOwnProperty('featureType') ? 'feature:' + v.featureType : 'feature:all') + '|';
        result += (v.hasOwnProperty('elementType') ? 'element:' + v.elementType : 'element:all') + '|';
        v.stylers.forEach(function(val, i, a){
          var propertyname = Object.keys(val)[0];
          var propertyval = new String(val[propertyname]).replace('#', '0x');
          result += propertyname + ':' + propertyval + '|';
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(result);
    return encodeURIComponent(result);
  }
```

Alas, this code is outputting the following:

[image: Output]

(Right-click and select "copy URL" to see the full path I'm using -- the above is direct from the static images API)

...When instead it should look like this:

[image: London with style]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each single style must be supplied with a separate `style`-parameter:

```
 function get_static_style(styles) {
    var result = [];
    styles.forEach(function(v, i, a){
      var style='';
      if (v.stylers.length > 0) { // Needs to have a style rule to be valid.
        style += (v.hasOwnProperty('featureType') ? 'feature:' + v.featureType : 'feature:all') + '|';
        style += (v.hasOwnProperty('elementType') ? 'element:' + v.elementType : 'element:all') + '|';
        v.stylers.forEach(function(val, i, a){
          var propertyname = Object.keys(val)[0];
          var propertyval = val[propertyname].toString().replace('#', '0x');
          style += propertyname + ':' + propertyval + '|';
        });
      }
      result.push('style='+encodeURIComponent(style))
    });

    return result.join('&');
  }
```

---

[**watch the result**](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=51.5072,0.12750000000005457&zoom=9&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&style=style=&style=feature%3Awater%7Celement%3Aall%7Ccolor%3A0xd2dce6%7C&style=feature%3Aadministrative.country%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Cweight%3A1%7Ccolor%3A0xd5858f%7C&style=feature%3Aadministrative.country%7Celement%3Alabels.text.fill%7Ccolor%3A0x555555%7C&style=feature%3Aadministrative%7Celement%3Ageometry.stroke%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C&style=feature%3Aadministrative.country%7Celement%3Aall%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.highway%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A40%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.arterial%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A40%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.local%7Celement%3Aall%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Alandscape%7Celement%3Aall%7Chue%3A0xFFFFFF%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A100%7C&style=feature%3Alandscape.natural%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Csaturation%3A-100%7C&style=feature%3Alandscape.man_made%7Celement%3Ageometry.fill%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7Csaturation%3A-100%7C&style=feature%3Apoi.park%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A60%7C&style=feature%3Apoi%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Chue%3A0xFFFFFF%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Clightness%3A100%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C)

Comment: Ah! That totally makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The selected answer didn't work for me.
But only because I had a few objects without `styler` parameters.
I had to modify it like so:

```
function get_static_style(styles) {
    var result = [];
    styles.forEach(function(v, i, a){

        var style='';
        if( v.stylers ) { // only if there is a styler object
            if (v.stylers.length > 0) { // Needs to have a style rule to be valid.
                style += (v.hasOwnProperty('featureType') ? 'feature:' + v.featureType : 'feature:all') + '|';
                style += (v.hasOwnProperty('elementType') ? 'element:' + v.elementType : 'element:all') + '|';
                v.stylers.forEach(function(val, i, a){
                    var propertyname = Object.keys(val)[0];
                    var propertyval = val[propertyname].toString().replace('#', '0x');
                    // changed "new String()" based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5821991/1121532

                    style += propertyname + ':' + propertyval + '|';
                });
            }
        }
        result.push('style='+encodeURIComponent(style));
    });

    return result.join('&');
}
```

see it in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnGpb/1/

p.s: JSHint

Comment: This is working well for me. A great function for the library.

Answer (score 5):

This is a PHP method that does the same thing

```
public function mapStylesUrlArgs($mapStyleJson)
{
    $params = [];

    foreach (json_decode($mapStyleJson, true) as $style) {
        $styleString = '';

        if (isset($style['stylers']) && count($style['stylers']) > 0) {
            $styleString .= (isset($style['featureType']) ? ('feature:' . $style['featureType']) : 'feature:all') . '|';
            $styleString .= (isset($style['elementType']) ? ('element:' . $style['elementType']) : 'element:all') . '|';

            foreach ($style['stylers'] as $styler) {
                $propertyname = array_keys($styler)[0];
                $propertyval = str_replace('#', '0x', $styler[$propertyname]);
                $styleString .= $propertyname . ':' . $propertyval . '|';
            }
        }

        $styleString = substr($styleString, 0, strlen($styleString) - 1);

        $params[] = 'style=' . $styleString;
    }

    return implode("&", $params);
}
```

src: https://gist.github.com/WouterDS/5942b891cdad4fc90f40

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using simple `map`:

```
// Given styles array
const myStyles = [
{
  elementType: 'geometry',
  stylers: [
    {
      color: '#f5f5f5'
    }
  ]
},
{
  elementType: 'labels.icon',
  stylers: [
    {
      visibility: 'off'
    }
  ]
},
{
  elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
  stylers: [
    {
      color: '#616161'
    }
  ]
},
{
  elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
  stylers: [
    {
      color: '#f5f5f5'
    }
  ]
},
{
  featureType: 'administrative',
  elementType: 'geometry',
  stylers: [
    {
      visibility: 'off'
    }
  ]
},
{
  featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
  elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
  stylers: [
    {
      color: '#bdbdbd'
    }
  ]
}];

const buildStyles = (styles) => {
  return styles.map((val, idx) => {
    const { featureType, elementType, stylers } = val;
    const feature = `feature:${featureType || 'all'}`;
    const element = `element:${elementType || 'all'}`;
    const styles = stylers.map(style => {
      const name = Object.keys(style)[0];
      const val = styles[name].replace('#', '0x');
      return `${name}:${val}`;
    });

    return `style=${encodeURIComponent(`${feature}|${element}|${styles}|`)}`;
  }).join('&');
};

const stylesStr = buildStyles(myStyles);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution worked for me apart from one small error:

const val = styles[name].replace('#', '0x');

Should read:

const val = style[name].replace('#', '0x');

Answer (score 0):

I created this utility nodejs function for all Android developers.

**Save** the code below as `flatten-mapstyle.js` anyware.

**Run** using: `node flatten-mapstyle.js /path/to/your/style/style_json.json`

To **urlencode** output use `-e` flag, i.e: `node flatten-mapstyle.js style_json.json -e`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');

const args = process.argv.slice(2)

const filename = args[0]
const encode = args[1]

const exists = promisify(fs.exists);
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);


async function main() {
    try {
        if (filename == undefined || await !exists(filename)) {
            throw {
                'error': `file ${filename} does not exist`
            }
        }
        let json = await readFile(filename, 'utf8');
        console.log("=========COPY BELOW========")
        console.log(getStaticStyle(JSON.parse(json)))
        console.log("=========END OF COPY========")
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

main();

function getStaticStyle(styles) {
    var result = [];
    styles.forEach(function(v, i, a) {

        var style = '';
        if (v.stylers) { // only if there is a styler object
            if (v.stylers.length > 0) { // Needs to have a style rule to be valid.
                style += (v.hasOwnProperty('featureType') ? 'feature:' + v.featureType : 'feature:all') + '|';
                style += (v.hasOwnProperty('elementType') ? 'element:' + v.elementType : 'element:all') + '|';
                v.stylers.forEach(function(val, i, a) {
                    var propertyname = Object.keys(val)[0];
                    var propertyval = val[propertyname].toString().replace('#', '0x');
                    style += propertyname + ':' + propertyval + '|';
                });
            }
        }
        result.push('style=' + (encode == "-e" ? encodeURIComponent(style) : style));
    });

    return result.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMPROVED Javascript/Typescript** version

For those who want to **save some time**:

I made some improvements to use it directly with a Javascript/Typescript function, enjoy !!! :)

```
static getStaticStyleParams(gmapJson: Record<string, any>[]) {
    function isColor(value: string) {
      return /^#[0-9a-f]{6}$/i.test(value.toString());
    }
    function toColor(value: string) {
      return `0x${value.slice(1)}`;
    }

    function parse() {
      const currentItems: string[] = [];
      const separator = '|';

      currentItems.length = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < gmapJson.length; i++) {
        const item = gmapJson[i];
        const hasFeature = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, 'featureType');
        const hasElement = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, 'elementType');

        const stylers = item.stylers;
        let target = '';
        let style = '';

        if (!hasFeature && !hasElement) {
          target = 'feature:all';
        } else {
          if (hasFeature) {
            target = `feature:${item.featureType}`;
          }
          if (hasElement) {
            target = target ? target + separator : '';
            target += `element:${item.elementType}`;
          }
        }

        for (let s = 0; s < stylers.length; s++) {
          const styleItem = stylers[s],
            key = Object.keys(styleItem)[0]; // there is only one per element

          style = style ? style + separator : '';
          style += `${key}:${isColor(styleItem[key]) ? toColor(styleItem[key]) : styleItem[key]}`;
        }

        currentItems.push(target + separator + style);
      }

      return currentItems;
    }

    return `&style=${parse().join('&style=')}`;
  }
```